# How to catch "png error" with BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()?

Tags: android, graphics, error-handling, png

I have this method in my Android app:

```
public void displayImage(ByteArrayOutputStream pngData) {
    if (pngData != null) {
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(pngData.toByteArray(), 0, pngData.size()); // even when this generates a log error...
        if (image != null) { // ...this still evaluates true
            this.imageView.setImageBitmap(image); // ...and then this displays an all-black image
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes, `decodeByteArray` fails, and `D/skia: ------ png error bad adaptive filter value` appears in the console. However, `decodeByteArray` still returns a non-null image object. Then `setImageBitmap` displays an empty (all black) image.

I would like to simply skip displaying the image in this case, but I can't find a way to test for this error. In addition to `image != null`, I've also tried testing `image.getWidth() > 0`, `image.getByteCount() > 0` and `image.getDensity() > 0`, but they all evaluate to true for good or bad images. Is there a way to catch this?

Answer (score 0):

it is true that on different android devices the same interface bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("XXX.png"); would return different result. For example for the broken png file I upload (https://www.dropbox.com/s/vkhw44mtzut15zr/bad.png?dl=0), generally mobile devices would return a null bitmap but Nexus 6P returns a not empty bitmap but you can not preview it on your application.

Comment: Good observation. I saw the `bad adaptive filter value` error on a Pixel C with Android 7, but the same data on a Nexus 10 with Android 5 triggers `decode returned false`, and the bitmap image is null as I would expect.